# Autocomplete não vai para a página indicada

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocompletar

Estou usando o jQuery para criar um campo de pesquisa com "autocomplete" que está funcionando perfeitamente. Porém, não estou conseguindo fazer o direcionamento para o link, quando o usuário seleciona.

Meu código está assim:

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/jquery.js"></script>    

</head>

<div id="pesquisa" style="float: right; margin-top: 45px; margin-right: 10px;">  
   <form action="index.php?id=<?php echo $linha["id"]; ?>&tp=total" method="get" name="autocomplete" target="_self">
      <input id="autocomplete" title="Digite algo">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="button-icon">.</button>
   </form>
</div><!--pesquisa-->

<script src="libraries/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="libraries/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT 
    pags.title, 
    pags.keywords, 
    pags.tema
    FROM pags
    ORDER BY pags.id";

    $resultado = $PDO->query( $sql );
    $rows = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

    var availableTags = [

<?php
    foreach ($rows as $key => $linha) {

    echo '"' . $linha['title'] .' | ' . $linha['keywords'] . '",';

    }       
?>
    ""
    ];
    $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    });

    $( "#button" ).button();
    $( "#button-icon" ).button({
    icon: "ui-icon-gear",
    showLabel: false
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Onde estão os links e como seria feito esse redirecionamento? A pergunta está muito vaga.

Comment: O link está no action do formulário

Comment: Ok, mas isso é quando clica no botão ao lado do campo ou quando o usuário clica numa opção da lista?

Comment: Quando clicar no botão. Mas não consigo fazer nem uma coisa nem outra...

Answer (score 2):

Você pode submeter o formulário usando o evento `select` ([veja documentação](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)). Na função do evento busque o formulário usando `.closest("form")` e submeta com `.submit()`:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
   source: availableTags,
   select: function(){
      $(this).closest("form").submit();
   }
});
```

No caso do botão, basta adicionar o atributo `required` no campo que o formulário só será submetido de houver valor no campo:

```
<input required id="autocomplete" title="Digite algo">
       ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porém ainda não está funcionando. Nem a seleção do registro, nem o botão. O link é composto do nome da página (index.php) da variável da pesquisa (campo ID que só será obtido à partir da execução da QUERY) e de uma constante (&tp=total), porem não aparece nenhuma destas informações na URL após o botão ser acionado ou o input ser atualizado...

Comment: Troque o method `get` por `post`, mas no PHP vc usa $_GET

Comment: Ainda não deu certo. Apesar do script estar funcionando agora, não está indo para a página certa. Não traz qualquer valor na variável $_POST["autocomplete"]

Comment: Vc precisa colocar um `name`, além do id, no campo para pegar com POST: `name="autocomplete"`